# Reading a variable text file from variable directory using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and reckon I'm doing something wrong while trying to access a variable file(text file) from a variable directory. The code that I've written is:

```
filename = input('Enter filename')
dir = input('Enter directory')

with open('%s/%s.txt' %dir % filename,'r') as myfile:
    input = myfile.read().replace('\n','')
```

But I'm unable to access the file due to error which says:

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Where did you learn that syntax from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is wrong. Try this:

```
with open('%s/%s.txt' % (dirname, filename),'r') as myfile:
    input = myfile.read().replace('\n','')
```

Instead of the above you could also use named parameters using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
with open('{dirname}/{filename}.txt'.format(dirname=dirname, filename=filename),'r') as myfile:
    input = myfile.read().replace('\n','')
```

Also, note that [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) is an in-built function so you should not use that as a variable. I changed it to `dirname` in the example.

Comment: I get the following error:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<built-in function dir>/asthma.txt'